# How we can fetch data in hierarchy in cakephp from two or more tables

Tags: cakephp-2.0

Here I do have problem My table I have studied cookbook but still don't find some appropriate answer because i am beginner I have also searched Stack overflow but still in problem
i have read this [from CookBoook 2X](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html)   but not get final answer 
I do have a question that i have two tables one is inhabited from other

```
parent table=> Countries
Child table=> State
Grand Child=> City
```

I want to get data of countries simply from citiesController
i do use

```
$this->City->find('all');
```

but its only fetch data related cities and States

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boy use this

```
   $this->City->recursive=2;
    $Cities= $this->City->find('all');
```

Using this recursive property, Cake will know about the depth of the result that needs to be generated when find() and read() methods